# I have configured Django REST Framework API Key, I want to expose one API to call without API key in Authorization header, What configuration needed?

Tags: django

This is the code block I have added to my settings.py file. Is there any way to expose an API that can be called without an authorization header?
I don't want to use the JWT token. There is no user interface in the application its an integrator project.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework_api_key.permissions.HasAPIKey",
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `AllowAny` permission, then you will not need any authorization, authorization header and token etc. API will be public/open to all.

Add `AllowAny` in the `permission_classes` attribute of the view.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class ExampleView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

Note:
It does not have to be a `generics.***APIView`. It works with `APIView` too. Also for the function-based views, you can use decorators.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([permissions.AllowAny])
def example_view(request, format=None):
    ...
```

Reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#allowany